# Multiple pipelines for the same branch

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, gitlab-pipelines

GitLab CI offers very nice flexibility and multiple features. Because of that is not obvious how particular configurations should be achieved using GitLabCI yaml, scheduler, etc.

I am interested to setup a workflow, which I am presenting below in a simplified way.

I use only master branch, where I want my primary pipeline to kick in after every commit. This pipeline will build and test my package.
I want to also have a scheduled nightly pipeline which publish website of my package. So it takes the most recent artifacts, generate documentation and publish that together to GitLab pages.

So, basically I want to have two different pipelines being run on the same branch. Primary is the regular one, and the secondary is the one run by scheduler.

In my real use case I want to have 2 scheduled nightly pipelines and one weekly pipeline, so including primary one (every commit), total 4 pipelines, still for the same branch.

Using `only`/`rules` doesn't really address that. There is a new `workflow` command, which could in theory, be applied here, by branching

```
if scheduled then
  include nightly.gitlab-ci.yml
else
  include primary.gitlab-ci.yml
```

But I don't think it is possible.

What could be the most user friendly solution is to give scheduled pipelines an option to choose custom `.gitlab-ci.yml` file rather than starting default one.

Any ideas how to achieve configuration I am looking for?

The only way I have in mind is to keep having another branch, clone of master, where I need to replace `.gitlab-ci.yml` every evening. Which requires extra workstation to automate that.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to have 2 scheduled nightly pipelines and one weekly pipeline, so including primary one (every commit), total 4 pipelines, still for the same branch

I understand you want 4 pipelines such as:

- *Primary* pipeline run for commited changes
- *Nightly 1* pipeline running every night
- *Nightly 2* pipeline running every night, different than *Nightly 1*
- *Weekly* pipeline running every week

For *Primary* you can leverage [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) to only run jobs on commited change with [`$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html):

```yaml
# Primary job running only on push (i.e. on pushed commits)
# It won't run on schedule
primary_pipeline_job:
  stage: build
  script:
  - echo "I will run only on commited changes"
  # [...]
  rules:
  - if $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
```

For multiple scheduled pipelines, you can leverage both [`$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) and **custom variables set on your schedule config** such as:

```yaml
# nightly_pipeline_1_job_A and job_B will be run on scheduled pipelines
# only on schedule and when RUN_NIGHTLY_PIPELINE_1 == "true"
nightly_pipeline_1_job_A:
  # [...]
  rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" && $RUN_NIGHTLY_PIPELINE_1 == "true"

nightly_pipeline_1_job_B:
  # [...]
  rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" && $RUN_NIGHTLY_PIPELINE_1 == "true"

# nightly_pipeline_2_job_A will be run on scheduled pipelines
# only on schedule and when RUN_NIGHTLY_PIPELINE_2 == "true"
nightly_pipeline_1_job_B:
  # [...]
  rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" && $RUN_NIGHTLY_PIPELINE_2 == "true"

# weekly_pipeline_job will be run on scheduled pipelines
# only on schedule and when RUN_WEEKLY_PIPELINE == "true"
weekly_pipeline_job:
  # [...]
  rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" && $RUN_WEEKLY_PIPELINE == "true"
```

In your GitlabCI settings *CI/CD > Schedules > [Your schedule] > Variables* you can related variables. For example, for `Nightly pipeline 1`:

[image]

---

If you have multiple jobs you want to run on the same pipeline, instead of duplicating `rules:`, you can leverage [`extends`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends) such as:

```
.nightly_pipeline_1:
  rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" && $RUN_NIGHTLY_PIPELINE_1 == "true"

nightly_pipeline_1_job_A:
  extends: .nightly_pipeline_1
  # [...]

nightly_pipeline_1_job_B:
  extends: .nightly_pipeline_1
  # [...]
```

Comment: good answer, it is still a workaround for missing functionality, but probably the best possible as of now

Answer (score 0):

If you have pipeline which launches after every commit then just add deploy stage to it which will only be executed for scheduled triggers. That way you will need only one CI configuration:

```yaml
build_job:
...
test_job:
...
deploy_job:
...
  only:
    - schedules
```

I understand your original question is if you can run deploy job on scheduled pipelines only but why not test it and build anew in such case? It is usually a good practice to test and build your artifacts just before deploy especially if it doesn't take too much time.

Comment: Deploy is not just one stage but whole pipeline. Moreover, as explained in my Q, I want to have 3 scheduled pipelines. One of them, a deploy pipeline just collects information from other pipelines are produce a table of successes/failures, mentioning commit sha because daily/weekly/every-commit pipelines will most often have different sha. Weekly pipeline is a heavy test suite that takes up to 100h. Unfortunately your solution doesn't seem to be applicable.

Comment: From my experience it is easy to work with Gitlab + Gitlab CI for simple workflows but for more advanced I'd use Jenkins or other tool which provides much more functionality. If you still need to do it on Gitlab there is [ongoing issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/20769) with similar problem and some users suggest how to bypass it, eg. [setting variable by schedules](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/20769#note_215109166).